# How to Reshape my data for CNN? ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 267 into shape (267,2)

Tags: python, input, conv-neural-network

```
#Input 13 features
#Output Binary
# 297 data points    
x = x.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]].values
y1= y['Target'}     

# Stratified K fold cross Validation
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=None)

num_features=13
num_predictions=2

#Splitting data     
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x,y1):

     x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y1[train_index], y1[test_index]

     # Standardization of data
     sc=StandardScaler(0,1)
     X_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
     X_test = sc.transform(x_test)

     print(X_train.shape) # o/p: (267,13)
     Print(y_train.shape) # o/p: (267)

     X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], -1))
     X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], -1))

     # Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
     y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (y_train.shape[0], num_predictions))
     y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (y_test.shape[0], num_predictions))

     verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 10, 32

     n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],y_train.shape[1]

     model = Sequential()
     model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape (n_timesteps,n_features)))
     model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
     model.add(Dropout(0.5))
     model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
     model.add(Flatten())
     model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
     model.add(Dense(297, activation='softmax'))
     model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
     # fit network
     model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
     # evaluate model
     accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
     print(accuracy)
```

How can i input data to feed into CNN which requires 3 dimensions of data. How to solve issue

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 267 into shape (267,2).

Comment: Hello Sujay Ravi, and welcome at Stack Overflow :-) Please review the page about ["how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question such that it attracts helpful answers. In particular, you should boil down your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How do i transform my input data of shape (297, 13 ) to feed into CNN?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a line of 100 squares, and you want to make it a rectangle. Could you turn it into a rectangle by making it 2x100? No, but you could make it 50x2.

In short, you can't make a rectangle that has more values than the original.